# Why isn't this Bootstrap 3 column working correctly?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Look at this [page link](http://www.germanmagicfarm.com/) and scroll to bottom, resize the window to see what I mean,

It seems on *tablet sizes* (portrait view - like on ipad size for example) that  one of my column; very last item in the SERVICES section, isn't working quite right can someone look at it for me?

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="service-item">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-shield fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
        </span>
        <h4><strong>Clinics: Josef Maier</strong></h4>
        <p>Josef Maier:  level 3 course designer</p>
        <p>Coming this October!</p>

        <a href="clinics.html" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Actually all of those at the bottom of the page are coded the same but when resized to tablet portrait size the last one is getting pushed down...

One might think that the paragraph text in one of the other Services item is causing this by being too long, but I already tried adjusting it so that the paragraph text and heading items were shorter and it was still happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your columns are working correctly, the problem is that in your first `col-md-3 col-sm-6` you have a `<br>`

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
       <div class="service-item">
           <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
           <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
           <i class="fa fa-bullhorn fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                        </span>
           <h4>
                <strong>Lessons</strong>
           </h4>
           <p>Learn in a group or individually</p>
           <br> /*here is the br*/

           <a href="services.html#lessons" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
      </div>
</div>
```

So your first `col-md-3` is greater than the second one so it push your last `col-md-3` one line bellow.

To fix it just remove tha `<br>` and to prevent that behavior if the content of the `col-sm-6` changes set a height to your `col-sm-6`, e.g 275px 
which is the highest of the largest.

Answer (score 0):

This is result of running [pesticide](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pesticide-for-chrome/bblbgcheenepgnnajgfpiicnbbdmmooh) on your website

[image: your website now]

Grids are working fine, Actually, the first `col-md-3` is longer than the second, so it push the last `col-md-3` to next row.

[image: after edit on website]

I Just added `height: 250px` to class `service-item`

Happy Coding !